# Draw a curved line with text (node to node) using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrow-curve

I am preparing a figure like this one:

[image]

But I couldn't draw the curved line from the middle point of the green shape to another node (as shown in figure). Also the brace under A and C node. How can achieve that?

Those should be color independent and the text (This line with text) should be curved as the line.

I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.75in}{0.75in}{*} %left-right
\setulmarginsandblock{1.0in}{1.0in}{*} %top-bottom
\checkandfixthelayout
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) {A};
        \node [above right=of a] (b) {B};
        \node [right=of a] (c) {C};
        \node [below=of c] (d) {D};
        \draw[thick, green] ([shift={(-3mm,-3mm)}]a.south west) to[closed, curve through={(a.south east) .. (b.south east) .. ([shift={(+3mm,+3mm)}]b.north east)..(b.north west)..(a.north west)}]  cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: curves and texts]

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.75in}{0.75in}{*} %left-right
\setulmarginsandblock{1.0in}{1.0in}{*} %top-bottom
\checkandfixthelayout
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) {A};
        \node [above right=of a] (b) {B};
        \node [right=of a] (c) {C};
        \node [below=of c] (d) {D};
        \draw[thick, green] ([shift={(-3mm,-3mm)}]a.south west) to[closed, curve through={(a.south east) .. (b.south east) .. ([shift={(+3mm,+3mm)}]b.north east)  ..(b.north west)..(a.north west)}]  cycle;
        
        \draw[->,orange,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=center,text={Your bent text}}}] ([shift={(+3mm,+3mm)}]b.north east) to[out=20,in=20] (d) ;
        
        \draw [red,thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror,raise=1ex}]
  (a.west) -- (c.east) node[midway,yshift=-1.5em]{both items};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the thing what I wanted to do. @SebGlav Thank you so much.